# SQL Server 2019 PolyBase connection to SQL Server 2016 - Error

Tags: sql-server-2016, polybase, sql-server-2019

I was trying to setup a linked server between SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server 2016 but I have been consistently getting the error as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE PolyBaseSQL
    WITH ( 
    LOCATION = 'sqlserver://NYCSQL10.nydomain.net\ACT:1488',
    -- PUSHDOWN = ON | OFF,
      CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials
    );
    GO
```

Error:

> Msg 105001, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   External access operation failed because the location URI is invalid. Revise the URI and try again

Has anyone worked on something similar?

grajee

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df4841e5-57f3-451a-94c9-486cab2a431b/sqlserver-2019-polybase-external-access-operation-failed-because-the-location-uri-is-invalid?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just answered your question on the MSDN forum, but I thought I should answer it here as well.

Creating external table from SQL 2019, to SQL 2016/17 works fine. The issue you experience is that the `LOCATION` argument is just that; the location of the physical server your SQL instance is on. If you want to connect to an instance other than default, you would need to use the `CONNECTION_OPTIONS` argument.

So something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE PolyBaseSQL
WITH 
( 
   LOCATION = 'sqlserver://NYCSQL10.nydomain.net',
   -- PUSHDOWN = ON | OFF,
   CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'Server=NYCSQL10\ACT:1488'
   CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials
);
GO
```

Hope this helps.